# Can't load assembly that isn't explicitly used in my project

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reference, roslyn

I need to load these 4 assemblies on the fly:

```cs
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis",
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp",
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features",
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features"
```

They all come from nuget packages referenced in a project separate from the startup project.

But when I try loading them like this:

```cs
Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis"),
Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp"),
Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features"),
Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features")
// this doesn't work either:
// Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")
```

I get a FileNotFoundException on the `Assembly.Load(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features)` call.

However, loading the dll directly from the packages directory like so:

```cs
Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\project\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.3.9.0-2.20525.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.dll")
```

works perfectly fine.

I've also noticed that the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.dll isn't copied to the startup project bin directory, while the three other dlls are. I suspect that it's because I'm not explicitly using that assembly in my own code, it's just loaded using reflection and then immediately sent to external code.

My complete intended usage/implementation looks like this

```cs
public static Document CreateDocument(string assemblyName, IEnumerable<PortableExecutableReference> referensMetadata, string documentName = "Script", 
            IEnumerable<Assembly> hostedAssemblies = null)
{
    // To prevent "The language 'C#' is not supported." exception
    var _ = typeof(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Formatting.CSharpFormattingOptions);

    var mefHostRequiredAssemblies = new List<Assembly>
    {
        Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis"),
        Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp"),
        Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features"),
        Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features")
    };

    if (hostedAssemblies != null)
    {
        mefHostRequiredAssemblies.AddRange(hostedAssemblies);
    }

    var partTypes = MefHostServices.DefaultAssemblies.Concat(mefHostRequiredAssemblies)
        .Distinct()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        .ToArray();

    var compositionContext = new ContainerConfiguration()
        .WithParts(partTypes)
        .CreateContainer();

    var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace(MefHostServices.Create(compositionContext));

    var project = ProjectInfo.Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(), VersionStamp.Create(),
        assemblyName, assemblyName, LanguageNames.CSharp)
        .WithMetadataReferences(referensMetadata);

    var documentId = DocumentId.CreateNewId(project.Id);
    var documentInfo = DocumentInfo.Create(documentId, documentName,
            loader: TextLoader.From(
                TextAndVersion.Create(
                    SourceText.From(string.Empty), VersionStamp.Create())
                )
            );


    return workspace.CurrentSolution.AddProject(project)
        .AddDocument(documentInfo)
        .GetDocument(documentId);
}
```

My question is what am I doing wrong? How come I can't load references I've explicitly added to the project?

Comment: If the DLL isn't getting copied to your build, try setting the property "Copy Local" of the reference to "True."

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's already set to true :/

Comment: @RobertHarvey I should also mention that the references are in a separate project from the startup project and that the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.dll does appear in the separate project bin directory, just not in the startup project bin directory. I'm not entirely sure it's related to the problem